# Showing that $A$ and $B^c$ are independent given $A$ and $B$ are independent

Tags: probability

This problem is from the book, "Introduction to Probability" by Hoel, Port and Stone. It is problem 34 on page 25.

Problem:

Let $A$ and $B$ denote two independent events. Prove that $A$ and $B^c$ are independent.

Answer:

To show that $A$ and $B^c$ are independent, we I attempt to show that:
$$ P(A \cap B^c ) = P(A)P(B^c) $$ 
Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have:
\begin{align*}
P(A \cap B ) &= P(A)P(B) \\
P( A \cup B^c ) &= P(A) + P(B^c) - P(A \cap B^c ) \\
P(A \cap B^c ) &= P( A \cup B^c ) - P(A) - P(B^c) \\
P(A \cap B^c ) &= P( A \cup B^c ) - P(A) - ( 1 - P(B) ) \\
P(A \cap B^c ) &= P( A \cup B^c ) - P(A) - 1 + P(B)
\end{align*}

Now, I feel stuck. How do I finish the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=A\cap (B\cup B^c)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$

implies $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)-P(A\cap B\cap B^c)$, we deduce that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$.

$P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)(1-P(B))=P(A)P(B^c).$

Comment: I think you were fastest (+1). So, will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c) =A$ and $B\cap B^c=\emptyset$ we have
$$P(A\cap B) +P(A\cap B^c) =P(A) $$
Thus
$$P(A\cap B^c) =P(A) - P(A\cap B) =P(A) - P(A) P(B) =P(A) (1-P(B))=P(A)P(B^c)$$